# Spring configs for webapps -> location in WEB-INF mandatory?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have just finished building my up from bottom (database) over DAO and business layer. Now I am getting warm with the presentation layer for which I chose Spring MVC.

I have checked out the example delivered with spring-webflow-samples/booking-mvc. I was wondering why all spring configs are located in webapp/WEB-INF/config rather than java/resources. Since I have mine in latter, I wonder if it is required to have them in one particular place.

Thanks & Cheers
ER

Comment: should we assume you are using maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebApplicationContext` loads resources by default relative to WEB-INF. You can always prefix your resources with `classpath:/` to force loading from the class resources, or instantiate your own instance of WebApplicationContext, passing in a `ResourceLoader` that manages loading resources from the classpath by default.

Comment: O.k., but what really bothers me is that I have my entity manager in the resources dir, right now. If I leave it there and remove it from the one in webappcontext ... will the server find it automatically?